# Можно ли использовать переменную JSON Extractor в другом треде?

Tags: jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование

Всем привет.
Суть вопроса в заголовке. Если нельзя его использовать, то как можно передать переменную в другой тред, если сама переменная меняется с каждым запросом?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

Переменная в другом потоке не будет видна, если вам нужно сделать ее доступной глобально - нужно сохранить переменную в property при помощи функции [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) ну или [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) если логика более сложная, например второй поток должен подождать пока переменная не будет задана.

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо, будем пробовать :)